# OpenApi - CodeGeneration - Avoid/Modify Generation Of Version In Header Comments

Tags: java, code-generation, openapi

We are generating java clients/models by the gradle plugin:
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator-gradle-plugin/README.adoc

Generation works fine, and the header of the generated files locks like this, just an example:

[image]

Is there a way to change the **version-string** for the generation to a fix value without changing the whole gradle-version? Or even customize the generation of the file-header-comments somehow?

This would be very helpful to avoid too much commit-changes in the generated models each time, for files that are not affected by the current modifications.

```
/**
 * Client classes generation (java)
 */
task generateApiCodeJavaClient(type: ext.GenerateTask) {
    group = "openapi tools"
    dependsOn "generateOpenApiDocs"

    generatorName = "java"

    inputSpec = openApiYamlPath
    outputDir = project.ext.javaCodeDir

    inputs.file inputSpec
    outputs.dir outputDir
   
    configOptions = [
            dateLibrary: "java8",
            java8: "true",
            hideGenerationTimestamp: "true",
            library: "resttemplate"
    ]
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanx.

Comment: BTW: the same version string appears also each time in the generated method init(), see: 
setUserAgent("OpenAPI-Generator/5.0.0-dev.2.uncommitted+enable.actuator.c81cff4/java");

Comment: This version is probably taken from the `info.version` value in your OpenAPI file. Can you change it there instead?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it has nothing directly to do with the openapi-generator-gradle-plugin, rather than with schema definition. Modifying the version in io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.info-Annotation fixed this issue.

[image]

There is also another way to modify the version text for the Swagger-Application-Start, but this did not work for me, maybe parameters are not 100% correct. See commented-out line with 'forkProperties'. If someone knows anything about this comments are welcome.

```
openApi {
    // http://localhost:58427/openapi/api-docs.yaml
    apiDocsUrl.set("http://localhost:$openApiPort/openapi/api-docs.yaml")
    outputDir.set(file("$openApiYamlLocation"))
    outputFileName.set("$openApiYamlFileName")
    //forkProperties = "-Dspring-boot.run.arguments='--spring.application.version=$productWinVersion'"
    waitTimeInSeconds.set(120)
}
```